# Steer a flock towards a target? Like in pikmin?

Tags: physics, ai, steering-behaviors

Can a flock be steered towards a target ?

I've seen that flocking behavior has the alignement behavior, but can it be directed and steered toward a goal ?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=BKJyv4uqsWI#t=305

Comment: http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/gdc99/ - flocking is just a combination of three steering behaviors and there's no reason you can't add a fourth or even more.

Comment: would be great to have simple example of those algo, because opensteer is a little big. I'm also puzzled by how opensteer handle orientation, I'm trying to replicate those behavior with a physics libs (box2d), and I'm trying to make those behavior without orientation

Comment: Read the paper, not the OpenSteer code.  The math is really simple and should be trivial to reimplement from scratch yourself.